# Merge hash into arrays while using loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Currently I am getting an array of hashes by doing this:

```
f = File.open("public/odds/test.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
path = "//demo/test1/test"
xml.xpath(path).map do |x|
{'country' => x.parent}
end
```

A sample of my result for this:

```
[{"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"}]
```

Now as I have different xml files, I am doing a loop to go through all the files:

```
@files = ['a', 'b', 'c']
@files.each do |file|
f = File.open("public/odds/#{file}.xml)
xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
path = "//demo/test1/test"
xml.xpath(path).map do |x|
{'country' => x.parent}
end
```

As it is looping through each file, I expect to get 3 different results like this `[{"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"}]`. How can I merge them together so that they are in 1 array?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to inject results? [`Array#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) comes to the rescue:

```
path = "//demo/test1/test"
#      ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
result = @files.inject([]) do |memo, file|
  File.open("public/odds/#{file}.xml") do |f|
    xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
#   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    memo << xml.xpath(path).map do |x|
              {'country' => x.parent}
            end
  end
end.flatten
puts result
#⇒ [ {"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"},
#     ...
#     ... ]
```

Also, consider to use a [`File#open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) with a block. In your code the opened files remain unclosed, while the block will close them automatically on return. Whether one still wants to use `File#new` (≡ `File#open` without block,) one should explicitly call `f.close` as soon as the file is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to mark this as the correct answer, but I wonder why my result return as  `[ [{"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"}], [{"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"}],[{"country"=>"france"}, {"country"=>"singapore"}, {"country"=>"thailand"}]]` ?

Comment: I used inject method along with flatten to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you try this way. just declare new array an push all hash inside that array `arr << {'country' => x.parent}` and replace your `map` by `each` loop

```
 arr=[]
    @files = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    @files.each do |file|
    f = File.open("public/odds/#{file}.xml)
    xml = Nokogiri::XML(f)
    path = "//demo/test1/test"
    xml.xpath(path).each do |x|
       arr << {'country' => x.parent}
    end
end

    return arr
```

Comment: i am considering it as function so return is used there. otherwise no need to used it. Just used arr variable

Comment: It is still ruby, not php. Function does not need to use `return` unless there is a quick-return pattern used for preliminary checks.

Comment: yes sure but i think more readble for OP so used return otherwise no need. here for more explanation to op so not using quick return.

Comment: Thanks. This is also a correct answer, but I chose to use the inject method.